# Can I switch a single speed mag rim into a six speed?

Tags: rims

I’m interested in getting mag rims for a hybrid bike that I own. Only problem is that mag rims come in single speeds not six. Is it possible to have mag rims modified to mount a six speed cassette?

---

The mag rims that I have are Skyway Tuff II single speed cassette.

[image: from https://www.albes.com/skyway-tuff-wheel-ii-mag-20-inch-wheelset/]

Answer (score 2):

Going from single speed to multi speed is akin to re-building the whole wheel, since you'll usually need to swap the hub and consequently need to put in new spokes and stuff.

However, a cursory google search shows several mag wheels for bicycles which take cassettes. I can't vouch for their quality or safety, but they exist.

A 6 speed "cassette" is almost surely a freewheel (i.e. the mechanism that allows you to coast without pedaling is in the thing that holds the sprockets, not in the hub of the wheel) and not a cassette, and this is a fairly outdated design. You'll likely end up upgrading to a 7/8 speed cassette if you make this switch (which may also involve spreading your frame to get the new wheel in, if possible (i.e. it is a steel frame)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention this in the original question but my rim size is 20” does that matter for fitting the 6 speed on the frame?

Comment: It sounds like your bike is children's bike or BMX, not what is usually called hybrid. A photo of the bike might help.

Comment: My bike is a Tonino Lamborghini 6 speed 20”. I’ll definitely add a picture in a moment. I’m aware that the Mag rims can be made with cassettes instead of a freewheel, But the conversion from the one speed cassette currently on the rims can be changed to the 6 speed I currently have on my bike.

Comment: @Lee - Fitting a multi-speed hub to a 20 inch rim can be problematic.  The spokes will be really short.  You need to be sure that the chosen hub has the smallest flanges possible.  Also, of course, the spoke count must match.

Comment: @DanielRHicks "mag rim" or "mag wheel" is a wheel made from single cast piece. They don't have separate rim, spokes and hubs.

Comment: This is what we call a [tag:BSO] -- a bike shaped object. It's not worth dumping money into it. By the time you spend the money to do anything other than just keep it running, you'll have outspent to get a better bike.

Comment: Money isn’t an issue. The bike that I have is rare and worth keeping. I just want to know if it’s possible to do the conversion or if these rims will have to be custom built from the factory.

Comment: @Lee In a minute's Googling, I found two of these bikes for sale for about £200 each. Obviously, do whatever you want with your bike, but this isn't a valuable bike and, putting random wheels on it will only make it less valuable to any putative collector.

Comment: Actually my bike had its frame custom forged by a couple of owners back and completely custom built for about $1,000. It came with papers to prove it. It’s literally the only one. I couldn’t find another one anywhere after searching the Internet for weeks on end to see if it was real.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you cannot modify a single speed hub (spoked or part of a mag wheel) to accept multiple sprockets.

The hub width will be such that it allows room for a single sprocket, so there just isn't space for multiple sprockets, for a given frame spacing.

Comment: Well, technically the threads for single and multi speed freewheels are the same. The problem with mag wheels is that you can't offset the rim to make room for wide freewheel.

Comment: It’s not a freewheel. I definitely have a cassette on my bike. All I want to know is if it’s possible to change the one speed cassette on the rims to a six speed cassette so I can still use my shifter. Money is not an issue when it comes to having this built. Maybe a longer wheel axel will help offset the wheel so the six speed cassette will fit?

Comment: The rear wheel in the photo in your question has threads for a single speed freewheel. You could fit a 6 speed freewheel and a longer axle but then the rim and tire would be offset to the left relative to the ends of the axle. You cannot convert this wheel to a freehub/cassette as the mechanisms are fundamentally different. See [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html) for an explanation - unless you paid a machine shop to bore out the center of the hub and replace it with the mechanism from a freehub hub, but you still have the problem that the rim would end up offset to the left.